# Loading dynamic service inside angular 2 service

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, websocket, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to do a sort of socket handler. So in my angular 2 code I got a service named "socket.service.ts".

This service import the socket io lib and create the socket.

But I'm trying to get different handlers from a json file.
For example :
The user edit the "handler" key in a config.json file and it should change the handler of the socket.

I want that this handler has an angular 2 service syntax. So I've tried to import this dynamic service with the

```
System.import(path).then()
```

But it's giving me a false.

Here's my socket.service :

```
private _byHandler() {
  var _this = this;

  this._initHandler((socketHandler) => {
    _this.config = socketHandler.getConfig(_this.config);
    _this._handler = socketHandler;
    _this._createSocket();
  });
}

private _initHandler(callback) {
  let _this   = this,
      handler = this.config.handler,
      path    = "./../handlers/socket/" + handler + "/" + handler + "handler";

  System.import(path).then(callback);
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I find the solution :
First my path variable wasn't good and we should know that the value return by System.import isn't the class itself but an object wich contain the class.

So in the .then() should do something like :

```
let handlerClass = null;
  for(let k in socketHandler) {
    handlerClass = k; //Get the first key of the object cause we don't know the class name
    break;
  }

  _this._handler = new socketHandler[handlerClass]();
```